# Was meint "Öffentlichen" in diesem Kontext?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "Öffentlichen" in this context? Please focus on italic part, possibly provide full sentence translation.

> Zur Arbeit nehme ich am liebsten das Rad, bei Schnee und Regen *sind dann aber doch die Öffentlichen angenehmer.*

Source: http://bfu.goethe.de/b2_mod_2MX6/lesen.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"die Öffentlichen" means public transport.

> I prefer to ride my bike to work, but public transport is more pleasant in snow and rain.

Sometimes "der öffentliche Personennahverkehr" or "die Öffentlichen" is even abbreviated as "die Öffis".

Comment: The reason it is "die Öffentlichen" is that it is short for "die öffentlichen Verkehrmittel".

Comment: Oder auch ÖPNV, als formalere Abkürzung statt Öffis.

Comment: *Verkehr**s**mittel, sorry.